# How to load Nested json data into a single column in druid

Tags: apache, druid

I am trying to load nested json data in Apache druid:

Data-->

```
{
    "a": "a_data",
    "b": "b_data",
    "c_blob_Column": {"aaaa"{"k":"sample"{"c":"sample2"}}}}

Spec -->

{ "type" : "kafka", "dataSchema" : { "dataSource" : "blob", "parser" : { "type" : "string", "parseSpec" : { "format" : "json", "dimensionsSpec" : { "dimensions" : [ "a", "b", "c_blob_Column"

        ]
      },
      "timestampSpec": {
        "column": "timestamp",
        "format": "iso"
      }
    }
  },
  "metricsSpec" : [],
  "granularitySpec" : {
    "type" : "uniform",
    "segmentGranularity" : "DAY",
    "queryGranularity" : "none",
     "rollup" : false
  }
},
"ioConfig" : {
    "topic":"blob_topic",
  "consumerProperties":{
     "bootstrap.servers":"<local server>"
  },
  "appendToExisting" : false,
  "useEarliestOffset": true,
  "taskDuration": "PT15M"
},
"tuningConfig" : {
   "type" : "kafka",
  "maxRowsPerSegment" : 5000000,
  "maxRowsInMemory" : 25000
}
}
```

Output columns-->
a,b,c_blob_Column,__time

I am able to load the data but the issue is in the column  c_blob_Column the data is  not coming as in json form data Could someone please help me to find  how to load the json blob data?

Comment: I think there's a colon missing after "aaaa" in c_blob_Column definition.

Answer (score 2):

you can use jq expression:

```
"flattenSpec": {
      "fields": [
        {
          "type": "jq",
          "name": "c_blob_Column",
          "expr": ".c_blob_Column | tojson"
        }
      ]
    }
```